# Marklogic: How to extract some element only from search result?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I have one xml document

sample.xml

```
<cities>
 <id>1<id>
 <country>India</country>
 <city>Mumbai</city>
</cities>
<cities>
 <id>2<id>
 <country>US</country>
 <city>California</city>
</cities>
<cities>
 <id>3<id>
 <country>India</country>
 <city>New Delhi</city>
</cities>
```

I want to perform search on Id and On the basis of id I want to fetch only one  element.
For ex:
if I search for id=1 I want

```
<cities>
 <id>1<id>
 <country>India</country>
 <city>Mumbai</city>
</cities>
```

only this to be returned

This would have been easy if cities were  part of different xml's, I would have simply done

> element-value-query

any suggestions how to tackle this with all the cities being part of one xml only?

Answer (score 0):

I got that working using FLOWR

```
for $x doc("path/sample.xml")/cities
where $x/id='1'
return $x
```

Comment: Reading a single document with all of the records on each query is, as you note, inefficient. A TDE could project a separate row for each city from the document into the indexes such that a query could match and read the correct row from the indexes instead of the document. As you also note, the best approach would be to create one document per record (which would still allow the TDE index but also other approaches).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below if  is **not** the root element:

cts:search(//cities, cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id"), "1"))

Use the below if  is the root element:

cts:search(/cities, cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id"), "1"))